# How to stop joint separation

Tags: modeling, animation

I have a problem with a model. I've rigged the model for animation, but what happens is that joints have a really weird separation, like this:

[image: Separation area]

How do I solve this? The model came in four parts. I made them one, but the same happens to where the models meet, i.e. arms to torso, legs to torso. How do I fix it?

Comment: You need to join the vertices or your weight painting will be really hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by unequal weights on the edges of the mesh sections. Essentially the bone is 'pulling' on the mesh a different amount on each edge. The two easiest options are to either join the loops (selecting both and pressing <kbd>W</kbd> and choosing remove doubles should do the trick) or carefully weight painting the edges to ensure both edges have the same weights.